# What is the definition of a solid?

Tags: solid-state-physics, states-of-matter, solid-mechanics

What is the definition of a [solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid)? What is the most general definition of a solid? Are amorphous materials (which can creep) like window glass considered solids? Are colloidal substances like proteins solids?

Comment: Single crystals creep also, so creep is not a parameter to use to argue that a material is not a solid. Colloids are colloids. Crystallized proteins are solids. In general, the question appears ill-defined.

Comment: Window glass doesn't creep.  That's a myth.

Comment: Anybody mind if I change it to pitch, then? Also, I think you linked to the answer in your question.

Comment: And if that's too hard to understand (As wikipedia articles are wont to be), then try the [Simple English](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid) version of it. It's written in English, using only the ten hundred most common words in the English language.

Comment: @JMac - Window glass doesn't creep noticeably under gravity - but unless it has an infinite Young's modulus it does creep

Comment: @MartinBeckett Yes, I was trying to use "creep" in the context I thought he was using it; but that's a really good point.  Mechanical creep will occur either way; but it's very unsubstantial under mostly gravity and normal temperatures (and isn't the reason older windows are thicker on the bottom, for example).

Comment: @MartinBeckett - classic creep has nothing to do with Young's modulus (although I guess with an infinite modulus there would be no stress in the material to drive non-isotropic point defect diffusion). Perhaps something best discussed over a beer somewhere...

Comment: What research have you done yourself? This reads like a homework question. Also: one question per post in the future please

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a hard definition of a solid - just like there isn't really an agreement on the number of states of matter.

A solid is generally/substantially/lots-of-weasel-words a material in a fixed arrangement that doesn't change shape much.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest definition is that solids are substances which can sustain shear forces.

Comment: Solids can't sustain shear forces ─ things like crystal-defect migration and other effects mean that they deform over time. It's just that the plasticity happens on timescales *way* longer than we care to measure.

Comment: I furnished the standard engineering definition. you have furnished the difference between the physicist's definition and the engineer's definition     
 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I usually think in a solid by multiple fashions/properties, that differ them from other states, all of them crack at some point, though.

The 'natural' example I can think of is that, differently from liquids and gases, the solids molecules are somehow fixed in its positions apart from vibrations that are macroscopically interpreted as temperature. In a liquid/gas, molecules not only vibrate, but translate along the material. (Off course, again, there are materials such as glass that doesn't couple with this view).

This gives rise, e. g., to different processes in heat exchange, being for solids heat conductivity, and for fluids convectivity.

Off course, sometimes we find a material that does not couple with the definition. The glass physical state still delivers a great deal of discussion. Recently, some folks assure the "inexistence" of physical state for the glass (neither liquid nor solid), based on the nonequilibrium state of it,

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022309317302685

Answer (score -1):

As I stated in the comments, SE wikipedia has a pretty...solid... definition of... ugh, nevermind, that was a terrible pun.

Anyways, they contrast solids to liquids by saying that solids **only change shape when force is applied,** as opposed to liquids and gases which, as SE wikipedia says, 'move randomly, a process called flow.'

Generally, solids are colder than liquids and gases. Except, apparently, when you're dealing with helium, which doesn't much care about rules, as this state diagram shows:

[image: Helium state diagram]

Specifically, though, solids don't have as much energy as liquids, so they don't vibrate as much and aren't able to displace themselves by Brownian motion.

Comment: And then there's helium...